# Clojure re-find returns entire string as first result

Tags: regex, clojure

I have a regular expression, which looks as follows

```
(def command-regex #"^(toggle|turn on|turn off)\s(\d*),(\d*)\sthrough\s(\d*),(\d*)$")
```

I'm trying to match the following types of input

```
turn on 887,9 through 959,629
turn on 454,398 through 844,448
turn off 539,243 through 559,965
```

However when I try

```
(re-find command-regex command)
```

I get the following output, with the entire string matched at the start

```
[turn on 887,9 through 959,629 turn on 887 9 959 629]
```

When really I want

```
[turn on 887 9 959 629]
```

Is there something wrong with my regular expression, or am I using Clojure regex functions incorrectly?

It's not a huge issue, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong. I'd just like to avoid have to return `(rest (re-find command-regex command))` at the end of my function as a workaround

Comment: Looks like it's a single match with all your capture groups. 0 = `turn on 887,9 through 959,629` 1 = `turn on` 2 = `887` 3 = `9` 4 = `959` 5 = `629`

Comment: Any way I can prevent it? since I haven't specified a match group for the entire string?

Comment: You can't prevent group 0, by default it is the entire match. When creating an output array, most engines _exclude_ group 0 when you have other groups. So, I don't know clojure way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it works. The regular expression is itself a group, so the first match will be the portion of the search string that matches the entire regex- whether or not there are any sub-groups in the regex. Make sense?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the entire regular expression itself was a match group, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing all of the groups. If you look at the doc for [re-find](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/re-find) you'll see that it says "Uses re-groups to return the groups".

Looking at the doc for [re-groups](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/re-groups), it says, "If there are nested groups, returns a vector of the groups, the first element being the entire match."

It's written this way, because it's just a wrapper around the Java regex functions. The Javadoc for [java.util.regex.Matcher.group(int)](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/re-find) that group 0 is the entire match.

Since you want all but the first group, you will indeed need to use something to drop the first element. You can use `rest` as you suggest, or:

`(drop 1 (re-find command-regex command))`

or if you want to keep it as a vector instead of a seq:

`(subvec (re-find command-regex command) 1)`